# How to use nested constants in Swift

Tags: swift

Using enums for constants seems to be a simple and elegant solution. Is there a way I can achieve a nested string output using enums?

For example, consider I have the following piece of code:

```
enum Const {
    enum Car {
        static let Door = "Door"
        static let Engine = "Engine"
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that I can get "Car| Door" as an output for `Const.Car.Door`? or "Car| Engine" as output for `Const.Car.Engine`? and "Car" as output for `Const.Car`?. I have some analytics constants defined in my current project similar to namespace pattern. It has a LOT of nested tracking events and would really help if I can achieve what I just described above.

What I require:

`Const.Car` should give the output "Car"

`Const.Car.Door` should give the output "Car| Door"

`Const.Car.Engine` should give the output "Car| Engine"

I have no idea on how to achieve that.

## EDIT:

This should be also be extendable,

For example,

`Const.Car.Door.Handle` should give the output "Car| Door| Handle"

`Const.Plane` should give the output "Plane"

`Const.Plane.Flaps` should give the output "Plane| Flaps"

Comment: `Const.Car` cannot be both a string *and* an enum (in `Const.Car.Door`)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But forget about enums, is there anyway that we can achieve this? It would make my code feel more structured.

Comment: Put differently: If `Const.Car == "Car"` then `Const.Car.Door` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator overloading may help you to achieve similar functionality. 
Please look at my solution, you can extend it a lot more

```
enum Vehicle: String {
    case car = "Car"
    case airplane = "Airplane"

    enum CarPart: String {
        case door = "Door"
        case window = "Window"
    }
}

func > (left: Vehicle, right: Vehicle.CarPart) -> String {
    return left.rawValue + right.rawValue
}


let string = .car > .window // "CarWindow"
```

Comment: But seems to me that having enums hierarchy more than 2 layers in depth may be more problematic. Operator overloading in such case can be achieved but may be difficult to implement. I personally would prefer @j-caicedo solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a time ago a similar problem which I managed to solve using struct and enum. In your case it would look like this:

```
struct Const{
   enum Car: String {
      case Door = "CarDoor"
      case Engine = "CarEngine"
   }
}

print("\(Const.Car.Door)") //CarDoor
print("\(Const.Car.Engine)") //CarEngine
```

I hope it fits you well.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly fulfil your requirements as it doesn't print "Car" when calling `Const.Car` but it may be somewhere for you to start:

```
enum Const {
    enum Car {
        static let identifier = "Car"
        static let Door = "\(Car.identifier)Door"
        static let Engine = "\(Car.identifier)Engine"
    }
}

print(Const.Car.Door) //CarDoor
print(Const.Car.Engine) //CarEngine
```

You can print "Car" by calling `Const.Car.identifier` though.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way I can think of is:

```
struct Const
{
    enum Car: String, CustomStringConvertible
    {
        case Door
        case Engine

        var description: String
        {
            return "Car\(self.rawValue)"
        }
    }
}

print("\(Const.Car.Door)")    // CarDoor
print("\(Const.Car.Engine)")  // CarEngine
```

Achieves what you need, makes it really easy to add new cases/parts without any boilerplate, and it would be simple to abstract away this functionality if you wish to support more vehicles.